# How to get data data attribute values at modal box section?

Tags: html

I have modal box like this:

```
<!-- Modal FOR PLAYERS-->
<div class="modal fade" id="Info" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h3 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Player profile for</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body info-player">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <label>GOALK IN THIS SEASON :</label> 11
            </div>

        </div>
      </div>            
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And i have added a Span Element where users can click on it to get the relevant data:

```
<span class="playerInfo" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Info">Info</span>
```

but now i wan to have some "data-XYZ='VALUE'" attributes in my SPAN Element and I want to parse to my modal box, how could I do someting like this?

I only know the way with an jquery onclick handler, but i think is also another better way or what you think?

Thanks for your help or any hints...

thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "I want to parse to my modal box" ?

Comment: @Dekel: these spans are into a while loop at getting data dynamicaly from a database and I want to display into my modalBox the data attribut values of my span element what i have created dynamically before...

Comment: it's still not clear "parse **to** my modal box". give an example of input/output/what you are looking for the final outcome to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the bootstrap `shown.bs.modal` event

> Occurs when the modal is fully shown (after CSS transitions have completed)

```
$('#Info').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
    $(".playerInfo").data("xyz"); //value

    // use the above data however you want
})
```

HTML:

```
<span class="playerInfo" data-xyz="value" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Info">Info</span>
```

Comment: WOW! I dint know that bootstrap offer such a great thing!
works really good!
Thx

Comment: last question: When i do something like this: <span class="playerInfo" data-playername="<?php echo $handleData['nameOfPlayer']?>"> --> its displays the output of the php content into my Site, but i just want to fill the data-playerinfo value of my Span Element wihtout displaying on the website... How can I do this?I get this data from the database... THANKS!

Comment: if you don't want any text value to the `<span>` element. Then just leave it empty & give the value only to `data-playername` -- `<span class="playerInfo" data-playername="<?php echo $handleData['nameOfPlayer']?>"> </span>` ... Not sure but is this what you're looking for?

Comment: my span looks like this (its not empty) the Word "INFO" is in there....
<span class="playerInfo" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Info" data-playername="<?php $handleData['name']?>" data-playersteam="<?php $handleData['teamName']?>" data-userid="<?php $_GET['userID']?>">INFO</span> but its always empty, but when i place and "echo" before my $_GET Parameters i have a succefully value BUT I also the website contains then the value of the echo, but i dont want to display the values of my data-attributes ;)

Comment: So you want the values of your data-attributes to be hidden in the DOM ??

Comment: i just wan to fill my span like this: <span class="playerInfo" data-playername="<?php echo $handleData['name']?>">  but then the content of the php variable is prompting on my websiten, but that is what i dont want... but when i remove the "echo" then i have no values in my $('#Info').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {} section!


>>>>>>> how can i solve this? How can i fill the data attributes with php content?

Comment: Aww ok, in that case try putting it in a variable & then call that variable on the data-attribute instead. Like `<?php $playername = echo $handleData['name'] ?>` OR `<?php $playername = $handleData['name'] ?>`(any1 of them should work, not sure which) & then use that variable in your span --  `<span class="playerInfo" data-playername="<?= $playername ?>` . I am no PHP expert but this should work for you. try & let me know